# run ruby from emacs buffer

Tags: ruby, emacs

How can I run a ruby piece of code from a buffer, without actually saving the buffer in a file? A scenario would be to 
a) switch to the scratch buffer
b) M-x ruby-mode
c) type ruby code
d) "compile" the buffer and print results in another buffer. I don't want to save the buffer contents in a file and then "compile" that file

UPDATE 1-9-2011
Which are the latest versions of ruby-mode and inf-ruby and where can I get them? I use the ubuntu natty version of ruby mode and the elpa version of inf-ruby of emacs 23.2. On a clean emacs config, the following config (see underneath) fail with:

```
can't convert nil into String 
from (irb):1:in `eval' 
from (irb):1".
```

Configuration is *just* the following, no other configuration directives in emacs.d:

```
(require 'ruby-mode)
(load-file "Configs/.emacs.d/elpa/inf-ruby-2.1/inf-ruby.el")

(autoload 'inf-ruby "inf-ruby" "Run an inferior Ruby pathrocess" t)
(autoload 'inf-ruby-keys "inf-ruby" "" t)
(eval-after-load 'ruby-mode
  '(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'inf-ruby-keys))
```

Comment: for me, inf-ruby doesn't seems to work properly for a buffer without a corresponding file e.g. if I M-x ruby-mode the scratch buffer and then M-x inf-ruby it doesn't work. Howecer, it works for ruby files.

Comment: how do you found inf-ruby compare to ruby-compilation? Seems we are looking same thing but more people recommend inf-ruby?

Comment: there is a beautiful piece of emacs lisp at https://github.com/jimweirich/emacs-setup-esk/blob/master/eval-buffer.el . You can evalulate a ruby/clojure/coffeescript/javascript buffer and it was dead easy to integrate it to my emacs setup. It evaluates the file the buffer displays though. Thanks Jim!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this with `inf-ruby.el`.

With `inf-ruby` installed, `M-x inf-ruby` starts a new ruby interpreter in the background, to which you can send code using the `ruby-send-*` commands, such as `ruby-send-region` (bound by default to `C-c C-r`). To send the whole buffer, select all with `C-x h` then hit `C-c C-r`.

*Update, 2011-09-02:* The latest version of `inf-ruby.el` (2.1.1, available in ELPA) is that maintained by 'nonsequitur' [on github](https://github.com/nonsequitur/inf-ruby), and snapshot packages are available in [Melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net).

Comment: this comes very very close. But I get a TypeError: can't convert nil into String error in the irb buffer.

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace somewhere? (To get the stacktrace, execute `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, then generate the error.)

Comment: inf-ruby works (check my OP comment above). last mile: the ruby buffer is a dumb terminal. can I change this? .bashrc sets and exports $TERM=xterm-256color

Comment: If you just want colors to be displayed, you might be able to use `(add-hook 'inferior-ruby-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-on)`. I don't believe you can turn the inf-ruby buffer into a smarter terminal, though.

Comment: it's not about colors. within the irb process, env variable $TERM=dumb . Which is quite inconvenient cause the irb's pager is only 1 line. Everytime I get a "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional" and underneath a "(press RETURN)". Ruby code is evaluated ok, but I have to press enter everytime in order for the result to be displayed. It's weird. Ruby evaluation works though. thx

Comment: I was receiving the "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional" as well and it turned out to be something in my .irbrc file because the error went away once I deleted my .irbrc file.

Answer (score 3):

#### A few options for you to try

**1. Rinari from [Github](https://github.com/eschulte/rinari/)**

It claims to be

*aimed towards making Emacs into a top-notch Ruby and Rails development
environment*

**2. ruby-compilation.el** is what you need.

There's a thread on that [here](http://fossplanet.com/f14/running-ruby-script-emacs-122875/) which I have used and found helpful.

Chris

Comment: I did that. M-x ruby-compilation-this-buffer gives me "Wrong type argument: stringp, nil". I used the version from https://github.com/eschulte/rinari/tree/master/util.

Comment: looking at ruby-compilation.el source: `ruby-compilation-this-buffer  (ruby-compilation-run (buffer-file-name)))`, whereas I want the contents of the buffer, not the contents of the file the buffer displays