# Emacs execute process continuously

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

There's a way to launch a process(continuously) in emacs?
For example, imagine ruby REPL, I expect launch the command "irb" in emacs and it should be in some some kinda of separated tab or buffer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [run ruby from emacs buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5742237/run-ruby-from-emacs-buffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific case of REPLs in Spacemacs you can start one for any supported language with `SPC m s i` then explore `SPC m s` prefix command for all the commands to interact with the REPL.

Answer (score 1):

```
M-x shell
irb
```

This will cover simple use cases. To get previous commands, type `M-p` and `M-n` instead of up and down.

You can get a fancier version from @legoscia's link.

Comment: Thanks, M-x shell resolves, I didn't know about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Can also do M-! to execute a single shell command and output to a new buffer.